# How to hide a button in Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, button

All I want to do is keep a button hidden until another button is pressed.

For example, Button 1 is visible, but Button 2 isn't. When I press Button 1, I need Button 2 to appear.

Also, I am programming in Xcode 6 using Swift.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Set `button2.alpha = 0` and it will be invisible.  You can even set it in Interface Builder so it starts out hidden.  Set `button2.alpha = 1` to make it visible.

Comment: Or set `button2.hidden = true` and it will be invisible.  You can set it to be hidden in Interface Builder so it starts out hidden.  Set `button2.hidden = false` to make it visible.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The sample code for hiding a button in Swift:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

// Create outlet for both the button
@IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //Set button2 hidden at start
    button2.hidden = true
}



//Here is the action when you press button1 which is visible
@IBAction func button1(sender: AnyObject) {
    //Make button2 Visible
    button2.hidden = false
    }

}
```

May be this can help you.

Comment: Ok...now what if Button two was a bar button?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27887218/how-to-hide-a-bar-button-item-for-certain-users