# How to hide a bar button item for certain users

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I have a settings bar button item (set as left bar button item). I only want to display it if the user is logged in.

I thought I could use the following for anonymous users

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
```

But then how would I show it as soon as they logged in?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can store a copy of the leftBarButtonItem in a `strong` property and update it after the users log in.

```
var leftBarButtonItem : UIBarButtonItem!
```

Inside `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "test", style:         UIBarButtonItem.Style.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

In logic:

```
if loggedIn
{
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.leftBarButtonItem
}
else
{
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
}
```

Comment: For those using a UINavigationBar by itself (not the controller version), you can add an IBOutlet reference and then set the right/left bar button items like so (notice the topItem? - I am using navigationBar as my reference name), where barButton is either an IBOutlet reference itself, code generated, or nil: navigationBar.topItem?.setLeftBarButton(barButton, animated: true)

Answer (score 6):

Best Way is just custom your Bar buttom with image. Set `barbuttom.image = nil` to Hide again assign the image to show. And dont forget to make the barbutton isEnabled as false.

Answer (score 3):

I have more that 2 menuitems and remove/add menuitem is an overhead. This code snippet worked for me.

```
func showMenuItem(){

    menuItemQuit.customView?.isHidden = false
    menuItemQuit.plainView.isHidden = false
}

func hideMenuItem(){

    menuItemQuit.customView?.isHidden = true
    menuItemQuit.plainView.isHidden = true
}
```

Comment: There is no plainView on the bar item.

Answer (score 2):

> if you want to hide/show UIBarButtonItem : For Swift 3

**Used below simple code :**

Declaration :

```
var doneButton = UIBarButtonItem()
```

In ViewDidLoad() or ViewWillAppear() or where you want to hide it : [hide bar button]

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
```

where you want to show bar button : [use anywhere in your code]

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.doneButton
        doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(YourViewController.dismissPicker))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5.x**

I faced the same dilemma and unfortunately no solution worked for me. Adding and removing buttons and related segues is unnecessarily too much of code when it includes multiple buttons on multiple screens. I have taken this approach for one or two buttons in the past and it becomes pretty ugly pretty fast.

The code `menuItemQuit.customView?.isHidden = false` doesn't seem to work on iOS 13 and above either, otherwise it would have made life so much easier.

My approach was to simply disable the bar button and change its tint to the navigation colour's tint.

In my app **What.To.Eat** I display bar buttons based on user's login status. Every element of the app is themed so that I could control all the colors based on various factors.

The navigation bar's color is named `commonButtonColor` and the bar buttons tint color is named `commonButtonColor`.

When I have to hide a bar button, I simply do the following:

```
let nav = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
nav?.tintColor = Theme.shared.titleText
nav?.barTintColor = Theme.shared.headerBg

if person.loggedIn {
    mealPrefsBarButton.tintColor = Theme.shared.commonButtonColor
    mealPrefsButton.isEnabled = true
} else {
    mealPrefsBarButton.tintColor = Theme.shared.headerBg
    mealPrefsButton.isEnabled = false
}
```

Where theme colors are defined in a separate file like this:

```
static var headerBg: UIColor {
    return UIColor(red: 0.965, green: 0.969, blue: 0.973, alpha: 1.00)
}
```

The above is a simplified version of what I do in the app to make it clear what I am doing. I hope it would help someone trying to achieve the same. It is simple solution and works just perfectly with a few lines of code.

As an example from the app, this is how two buttons appear and disappear based on whether the `My Recipes` button is selected or not:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have a same problem and solved.  I have a bar button item with image

```
barbtnClose.isEnabled = false
barbtnClose.image = nil

barbtnClose.customView?.isHidden = true // do not work in iOS 13
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

***A better solution and works even if you have set a custom navigation bar.***
Hide navigation bar button item or back button leftBarButtonItem / rightBarButtonItem

```
    if login == true {       
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil     
    } else { 
      print("set your bar button or return")
    }
```

**Hide back bar button in navigation controller with swift 5**

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil

self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```